# string.Format workaround with having a text and a float in same label

Tags: c#, string, string-formatting

I want to show the cpu usage in status bar of my application. For showing it I use the following code:

```
statusLabelCpu.Text = string.Format("CPU Load: {0:000.00}%", _cpuLoad.NextValue());
```

There are quite a big problems with the code above, it always shows 5 numbers, that is if load is nod 100%, it shows like `050.21%` This is too ugly!

I really don't want to use 2 labels. Is it possible to make this fixed width with only showing the actual digits? something like: (Take those dashes as indication of empty space!)

```
CPU Load:-0%     -
CPU Load:-1.1%   -
CPU Load:-8.01%  -
CPU Load:-99.99% -
CPU Load:-100%   -
CPU Load:-56.06% -
```

note: I have 2 labels in my status bar. this cpu counter goes to right. the one on the left has SPRING property set to true! if it has anything to do with my question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it is ok to pad it on the left side with blanks you can use this:

```
string.Format("CPU Load: {0,8:0.##}%", load)
```

When you want to pad to the right side, you have to do it this way becaus of the percent character after the number:

```
"CPU Load: " + string.Format("{0:0.##}%", load).PadRight(8)
```

The first results in

```
[CPU Load:     20,1%]
```

The second results in

```
[CPU Load: 20,1%   ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
statusLabelCpu.Text = string.Format("CPU Load: {0:0.00}%", _cpuLoad.NextValue());
```

Comment: Nah this dos not work, it causes the `CPU Load: ` to jump to the left when load is going higher. Also when load is 0, I want to show `CPU Load: 0%`  not 0.00%

Comment: You'll have to use a different format string depending on the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
String.Format("CPU Load: {0,-7:0.##}%", _cpuLoad.NextValue);
```

, is align -7 is pad to a length of 7 left aligned. # is print the digit if it exists.

Comment: The padding will be between the number and the % sign.

Comment: good point, didn't see that, Developer testing rides again. Looks like @nemesv has solved it below.